# Dynamic Web Scraping javascript:void(0). Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Not sure whats the best way to go about this.
I have a page that dynamically loads content but the tag is  `<a href="javascript:void(0);">Daily</a>`.

I've seen that the script actually sends off a network request that POST and its of type html.
Ideally i would like to get a copy of that response. What would be the best way of doing this. I've read all sort of thing Selenium, request-html, scrapy. I have the URL , Xpath so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  perhaps you could rephrase it with a little more detail?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if this is what you are asking. If you need to wait for the page to load dynamically, try something like this. I use this on Windows with chrome and beautiful soup. You can use whatever html parser you'd like

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

url = 'your url'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5) # time for page to load
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") #use bs4 to parse html

# do your thing here....

driver.quit()
```